# How to expose Images securely so user can use it directly in <img src="">

Tags: java, html, image, rest, model-view-controller

We have images in our Database.

End user want to access it using

```
<img src="https://mydata.ra.com/Api/image">
```

1. We informed end user to call our API and we will return base64 and use that. (Call from Backend code or javascript)
2. We are planning to give API which returns URL to end user and that URL contains information which expire in 15 minutes and end user can access image from that URL

What other strategy can be used here to provide access to images which can directly used in IMG Src?

Comment: Once I've developed a servlet which, after security checks (login and anti CSRF) translated an URI to an image in our DB, fetched the image and served it on its output.

Comment: you mean that all opinion suggested here will be correct? I am not sure what to use here actually so asked this question

Comment: I haven't vouched for closing the question, but I guess it was due to it being a bit broad. There are many ways to provide images from a DB over HTTP. In order to improve your question you should point out the customer rigid constraint (accessing the images via normal <img src=/> tag, that would probably limit the range of the answers.

Comment: @BigMike: Does changing last line unbroad it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Servlet.

In the `doGet()` method, after checking for security (login status, oauth, anti-CRSF, whatever you usually check), transform the path into a key to access the image on the database:

e.g.: if the Servlet is mapped on `/img/fetcher/*` you can call it with

```
<img src='{yourcontext}/img/fetcher/{imguuid}">
```

Then it's just a matter to retrieve the imguuid from the URI, translate it into you database key, perform a select and serve it on your servlet response.

```
        byte [] image = yourBuLogic.getImage(request.getRequestURI());

        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType("image/png"); // You can store this on the database as well
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length));
        response.getOutputStream().write(image);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
```